# Unknown display error ubuntu 18.04 (ryzen 5 4600h processor huawei matebook)

Tags: display, display-resolution, brightness, amd-ryzen, huawei

I installed ubuntu version 18.04 on my computer but I get an unknown display error, I can't change the screen resolution, I can't change the screen brightness, I tried all the solutions available on the internet, please help.

Comment: 18.04 will not work very well with the 4000-series processors. It would be better to use 20.04 if you need an LTS or 21.04 if you don’t mind the shorter upgrade cycles.

Comment: Thanks but since I will use the Ros application I have to use the 18.04 version.